# In "The Final Empire", how was Kelsier's plan supposed to work?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

I've just started reading *The Final Empire* by Brandon Sanderson and I think I have some misunderstandings about Kelsier's plan.

At the first meeting of the crew in Camon's safehouse Kelsier says:

> "But if we play this right, we might be able to force the Lord Ruler to send the palace guard - maybe even the Inquisitors - into the city to restore order. That will leave the palace itself exposed, giving Yeden a perfect opportunity to strike."

As the palace is located inside of the city, how can Yeden go in if the Inquisitors and the palace guard will be in the city? Please give no spoilers for events which come in the book after this meeting.

Comment: I can't post an answer without having read the books, but it's pretty clear.  Any defenders out of the palace will be unavailable to defend it; if the disturbances in the city are severe enough, if may not even be possible to recall them in a timely fashion.

Comment: I'd imagine it's because the city is larger than the palace, so the same number of guards spread amongst the whole city will be easier to slip past than those same guards concentrated just within the palace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that the city is a much larger area to defend.  With the guard spread out, Yeden's forces can be hidden nearby the palace, invade it with as little resistance as they can manage, and then hold it against any returning guard.